# 'Illegal attempt to call getOutputStream() after getWriter() has already been called' during Jersey test

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jackson, mockito

I have a Jersey endpoint that I am trying to test.

Endpoint:

```
@Path("image")
class ImageResource {

    @Inject
    private ImageService imageService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response save(ImageVO imageVO) {
        imageVO = imageService.save(imageVO);
        ResponseVO responseVO = new ResponseVO(true, imageVO);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(responseVO).build();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class ImageResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    private static final String BASE_ENDPOINT = "rest";
    private static final String IMAGE_ENDPOINT = "image";

    @Mock
    private ImageService imageService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ImageResource imageResource;

    @Override
    protected URI getBaseUri() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(super.getBaseUri()).path(BASE_ENDPOINT).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(imageResource);
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        ImageVO imageVO = new ImageVO();
        imageVO.setId("TEST");
        when(imageService.save(imageVO)).thenReturn(imageVO);

        Entity e = Entity.entity(imageVO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = target().path(IMAGE_ENDPOINT).request().post(e, Response.class);
        assertEquals(201, response.getStatus());

        ResponseVO responseVO = response.readEntity(ResponseVO.class);
        assertTrue(responseVO.isSuccess());
    }
}
```

And the exception:

```
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer start
INFO: Starting GrizzlyTestContainer...
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder process
SEVERE: Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:9998/rest/image, status=500, reason=Request failed.}}
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder release
WARNING: Attempt to release request processing resources has failed for a request.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to call getOutputStream() after getWriter() has already been called.
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.getNIOOutputStream(Response.java:621)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:646)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer$ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder$1.getOutputStream(ServerRuntime.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.flushBuffer(CommittingOutputStream.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:835)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.release(ServerRuntime.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:438)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:363)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer stop
INFO: Stopping GrizzlyTestContainer...
Jul 13, 2015 9:14:28 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
```

I have been beating my head against the wall with this for a couple of days, but can't find out the solution. I have multiple other endpoints that I test the same way, that do not have this issue. I'm using Jersey 2.6 with Java 6u5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and registering an `ExceptionMapper` allowed me to capture and output the error that was being thrown:

```
Unrecognized field "name" (Class com.example.ImageVO), not marked as ignorable at [Source:org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@13b7c28; line: 1, column: 149] (through reference chain: com.example.ImageVO["name"])
```

This is due to the fact that my `ImageVO` class has a public method named `getName`, but no `name` property. `POST`ing the `ImageVO` instance causes the JSON to have a key for `name` with a value of `null`, creating the exception.

There are two resolutions to this:

1. Setting the `DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` property for Jackson to false.
2. Use the actual JSON string for the post entity in the test:

   ```
   Entity e = Entity.entity("{\"id\":\"TEST\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   Response r = target().path(IMAGE_ENDPOINT).request.post(e, Response.class);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, I couldn't reproduce the exact problem, with what you have provided (though I did get *some* errors). I'll just post what I tested with, and maybe you can figure it out.

The major changes I made were:

- Just used Jersey's injection framework to handle the DI. You can see it where I `config.register(new AbstractBinder()` below. See more about it [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)
- Moved the `when` of the Mock to the point of configuration, instead of in the test method.

If you still can't get it working, try to create a new project with just the dependencies I've provided, and the one test case. If it works, then it's something you're not showing us, that may be the problem. If you want to provide a small Github project that reproduces the problem, I could have a look at it.

Maven Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Test case

```
import java.net.URI;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ImageServiceTest extends JerseyTest {

    private static final String BASE_ENDPOINT = "rest";
    private static final String IMAGE_ENDPOINT = "image";
    private static final ImageVO imageVO = new ImageVO("Test");

    public static interface ImageService {
        ImageVO save(ImageVO imageVo);
    }

    public static class ImageVO {
        public String id;
        public ImageVO() {}
        public ImageVO(String id) { this.id = id; }
    }

    public static class ResponseVO {
        public boolean cool;
        public ImageVO imageVo;
        public ResponseVO() {}
        public ResponseVO(boolean cool, ImageVO imageVo) {
            this.cool = cool; this.imageVo = imageVo;
        }
    }

    @Path("image")
    public static class ImageResource {

        @Inject
        private ImageService imageService;

        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response save(ImageVO imageVO) {
            imageVO = imageService.save(imageVO);
            ResponseVO responseVO = new ResponseVO(true, imageVO);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(responseVO).build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {

        final ImageService imageService = Mockito.mock(ImageService.class);
        when(imageService.save(imageVO)).thenReturn(imageVO);

        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        config.register(ImageResource.class);
        config.register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(imageService).to(ImageService.class);
            }
        });     
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    protected URI getBaseUri() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(super.getBaseUri()).path(BASE_ENDPOINT).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        Entity e = Entity.entity(imageVO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = target().path(IMAGE_ENDPOINT).request().post(e, Response.class);
        assertEquals(201, response.getStatus());

        ResponseVO responseVO = response.readEntity(ResponseVO.class);
        assertTrue(responseVO.cool);
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like there may be something else causing the issue that I've not listed. I will try to get a sample project on GitHub later tonight reproducing the error.

Comment: I've resolved the issue (see posted answer). Thanks again for the help and looking into it.